# Erroneous calls to stub in Cypress tests

Tags: cypress, sinon

I'm trying to assert that a method is called, so I've stubbed it:

```js
import * as dataActions from '../../../src/redux/data.actions';

it.only('sends start request', () => {
  cy.visit('/')
  const stub = cy.stub(dataActions, 'handleMessage', () => console.trace('HELLO FROM FAKE')).as('messageStub')
  expect(stub).not.to.be.called;
  cy.contains(/start/i).click() // this will call handleMessage
  expect(stub).to.be.called;
});
```

I have confirmed that the stub is definitely preventing the actual `handleMessage` from being called. However, the test fails on the final assertion. And it does so immediately, without any of Cypress's famous timeout.

But although it fails, the stub is somehow called four times. I can see "HELLO FROM FAKE" in the console, and the cypress log shows four invocations of the stub:

[image]

And the behavior is very strange: If I comment out the final assertion, the method is not stubbed (the actual implementation is called) and the fake is never called.

What is going on here?

UPDATE: A trip to the cypress docs implies that you're supposed to assert on the actual method, not the returned stub. However, the following gets the *exact* same result:

```js
it.only('sends start request', () => {
  cy.visit('/')
  
  cy.stub(dataActions, 'handleMessage', () => console.log('HELLO FROM FAKE')).as('messageStub')
  cy.contains(/start/i).click()
  expect(dataActions.handleMessage).to.have.been.called;
});
```

Comment: Cypress commands are asynchronous (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Commands-Are-Asynchronous). You can not expect right after it.

Comment: @andreyunugro do you mean `cy.contains(/start/i).click().then(() => expect(dataActions.handleMessage).to.have.been.called)`? That gives the exact same result. I also tried `then` off of the stub but it's not chainable.

Also, all the examples anywhere imply that this should work as I originally wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

Like it was said in the comments, you must wait for the click. So the correct code should be:

```
it.only('sends start request', () => {
  cy.visit('/')

  cy.stub(dataActions, 'handleMessage', () => console.log('HELLO FROM FAKE')).as('messageStub')
  cy.contains(/start/i).click().then(() => {
    expect(dataActions.handleMessage).to.have.been.called;
  });
});
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't work